# Groovy exercise with loops and booleans

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I'm new to Groovy and am trying to answer the exercise below..I can't see the error and doesn't work:
The program takes a series of numbers. If the current number is the same as the previous number, iy says "Same", if the current number is greater than the previous one, it says "Up", and if it's less than the previous one, it says "Down". It makes no response at all to the very first number.

```
println " Please enter a number: "
String s = System.console().readLine()
int num = Integer.parseInt(s)
int prev = 0
def finished = false
while(!finished) {
    println "and another: "
    s = System.console().readLine()
    int curr = Integer.parseInt(s)
    if (curr != 1) {
        if (curr > prev) {
           print " Up "
        } else if (curr < prev) {
           print " down "
        } else {
           print "Same "
        }
        prev = curr
    } else {
       finished = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that even compilable code?  What's `print = " Same"` supposed to be doing?  You seem to have if statements nested inside else blocks where you've already printed "Down"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indent the code correctly, you'll quickly see the problem

```
boolean finished = false
while(!finished) {
    int curr = 1
    println "Please enter a series of numbers: "
    String s = System.console().readLine()
    int n = Integer.parseInt(s)
    if (n != 1) { 
        n = curr + prev
        if (curr > prev) {
           print " Up"
        } else {
           print " Down"
           if (curr == prev) {
               print = " Same"
           } else {
               finished = true
           }
        }
    }
}
```

There are a lot of problems with this code.

- `curr == prev` check is inside the else, there should be a bracket after the `print " Down"`
- You don't define prev
- What is n doing here?
- What do you want to make your exit clause? `finished` can never be set to true as you will either be above/below/same. there's no 4th clause.
- You're never changing `prev`
- you have syntax error on the print line

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your answer. To be honest this is my first program and I didn't learning "def" so I can't use that in my home work

Comment: use `int` instaed. `def` would show you've just read ahead though.

Comment: well, i put a few pointers down, but yes, he should tag it as homework and we only throw hints at it

Comment: Thank you @MarkFisher you helped me a lot. I found out the errors. Its not perfect but for the first time EVER is not bad. I am happy.